# ¿Por qué recibo una respuesta diferente de la página al hacer mi request? Web Scrapping

Tags: python, scraping

Al realizar una petición GET a la página de Zalando, obtengo las siguientes respuestas.
[image: Requests que realizo desde mi navegador a Zalando]

Como pueden ver, me responde con cuatro redirecciones antes de obtener un status code 200.

Sin embargo, al realizar la Request desde mi código en Python, obtengo el código 200 en la primer respuesta. ¿Por qué sucede esto y no obtengo las redirecciones?
Mi código:

[image: Mi código]

Comment: Estas accediendo al usuario sin darle las cookies del login

Comment: Ya pude replicar todas las request, por alguna razón, en la última request me responde diferente. El problema anterior era q tenía los redirects activos

Comment: Seguiste la dirección de la [redireccion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475552/python-requests-library-redirect-new-url) ?; el navegador lo hace automáticamente pero request necesitas que lo gestiones un poco

Comment: era eso al finall, tuve que gestionar las redirecciones

Comment: igual no pude bypassear akamai, tengo q ver que hago con los sensoress

Comment: Que es lo que quieres hacer scrapear zalando? No puedes pasar akamai?

Comment: logearme inicialmente